# How do I implement this external merge sorting algorithm in C?

Tags: c, sorting, external-sorting

I need to simulate an external sorting algorithm considering the machine has only 96 bytes of memory available. I'm using 32 bytes structs that look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char usedmemory[31];
    char key;
}Register32;
```

I'm already do the point of splitting a big tobesorted.txt file in a number of 3 Register32 binaries. For instance:

```
 I N T E R C A L A C A O B A L A N C E A D A
```

is split into 8 files, which are internally sorted, ranging from file0.bin to file7.bin, containing 31 bytes of trash and 1 byte being the key which is used to sort the registers at all times.

```
file0.bin containing INT  
file1.bin containing CER  
file2.bin containing AAL  
file3.bin containing ACO  
file4.bin containing ABL  
file5.bin containing ACN  
file6.bin containing ADE  
file7.bin containing A
```

My assignment is to "merge" 2, 3 or 4 of these files into an exit file at any given time and keep merging them until I have the initial word all sorted out. Example: merging file0 with file1 would output C E I N R T
in the exit file. Of course the merging function should be generalized as to read each sorting key at a time and merge into an exit file regardless of file input size. My Merge function receives an array of files that can contain 2, 3 or 4 files (not known by function), the lowest index of mentioned array, the higher index and the exit file. It looks like this:

```
void MergeFunction(TypeFile* entry, int lowerindex,int higherindex, TypeFile exitfile){
       int i, j, count = 0;
}
```

TypeFile being only a `typedef FILE* TypeFile;`.

I know that I should compare each register's key at a time and then write the lowest to exitfile if I need to simulate the memory constrait, but I can't bring myself to think of a way to do it. The loop constraints and the cases in which inputs are 6 or more key characters long are melting my brain. In the end i just want o have that initial tobesorted.txt completely sorted, merging 2, 3 or 4 files at a time into a bigger one and proceeding to the next. This is already implemented, I just need to implement the Merge function.
Sorry if I made myself too difficult to understand, english is not my mother tongue. Appreciate any hep you guys can give.

Comment: 96 bytes. Riiiiight..   How much are you going to allocate as stack space?  With 96 bytes, you cannot run any file system I know of.  Even FAT-12 needed a 512-byte directory buffer.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I think the 96 bytes constrain is on the system's memory and not disk. Meaning the sorting program should not use more than 96 bytes. I could be wrong.

Comment: so are the first 31 bytes used at all? You seem to be saying they're not part of the sort key, and not part of the output, so why read them at all?

Comment: @Useless, it's just part of the assignment. We need to compare stuff that has content in order to see the difference between different sorting methods.

Comment: 1. Do you actually compare that data? 2. Do you actually output that data? If both answers are "no", then does the assignment _require_ you to read them into memory?

Comment: The structure implies that record size is 32 bytes, and if there is only 96 bytes to store records, there's only enough memory to hold 3 records at a time. How is this program supposed to be able to merge up to 4 files at a time?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have splitted and sorted original "chunk" files, what you need is something like this:

```
void mergeFiles(FILE* fIn1, FILE* fIn2, FILE* fOut)
{
    int ch1;
    int ch2;
    ch1 = fgetc(fIn1);
    ch2 = fgetc(fIn2);
    // merge files
    while ((ch1 != EOF) && (ch2 != EOF))
    {
        if (ch1 < ch2)
        {
            fputc(ch1, fOut);
            ch1 = fgetc(fIn1);
        }
        else
        {
            fputc(ch2, fOut);
            ch2 = fgetc(fIn2);
        }
    }

    // write the rest of one of the files
    if (ch2 == EOF)
    {
        while (ch1 != EOF)
        {
            fputc(ch1, fOut);
            ch1 = fgetc(fIn1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (ch2 != EOF)
        {
            fputc(ch2, fOut);
            ch2 = fgetc(fIn2);
        }
    }
    fflush(fOut);
}
```

The idea is that the merge stage of the merge sort algorithme requires you only to get first elements of each of the two sub-arrays being merged. Thus a stream input (such as file) fits this requirements as well (i.e. you don't have to read whole files into your RAM!). All you have to do is just to read two sorted files char-by-char, compare those chars, and output to the target file whichever is less. Then you merge these new combined files again until you get one big sorted file.